# Error when adding number to linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, null

I have this run time error that when I add a number bigger than anything inside my list. I do not see why. As I think the code should just add the node containing the number and refer to the null-pointer as the next node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
};

typedef struct Node Node;

void front(int, Node**);
void print(Node*);
void add(Node**,int);
Node**place(Node**,int);
void verwijder(Node**, int);
void clearList(Node**);

int main () {
int i;  
Node * l = 0;   
front(10,&l);
front(5,&l);
front(1,&l);
add(&l,9);
add(&l,5);
add(&l,11);
verwijder(&l,5);
verwijder(&l,9);
verwijder(&l,1);
clearList(&l);
free(l);
print(l);
}

void front(int number,Node ** start ) {
    Node * new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->value = number;
    new->next = *start;
    *start = new;
}

Node** place(Node ** start, int number){
    while((*start)->value < number && (*start) != 0) {
        start = &((*start)->next);
    }
    return start;
}

void add(Node ** start, int number) {
    Node ** space = place(start,number);
    Node * new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->value = number;
    new->next = *space;
    *space = new;
}

void verwijder(Node ** start, int number) {
      Node**space = place(start,number);
      Node * delete = *space;
      if(delete->value == number) {
      *space = (*space)->next;  
      }
      free(delete);
}

void print(Node * l) {
    while( l != 0) {
        printf("%i -> ",(l)->value);
        l = (l)->next;
    }
    printf("0 \n");
}

void clearList(Node** start) {
    Node * current = *start;
    while(current != 0) {
        *start = (*start)->next;
        free(current);
        current = *start;
    }
    free(current);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're checking whether the items in the list are less than `number` in function `place`? Also, to avoid always traversing the list to add an item, it'll probably be best to keep track of the last node i.e. tail. In this case, you can do it in `O(1)` instead.

Comment: I want newly added elements to be sorted, so I check when I get an element higher than the one I'm willing to add, and take the pointer towards that Node.

Comment: Have you managed to insert any items at all?

Comment: The items seem to get added as long as they don't exceed the value of the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with function - `Node** place(Node ** start, int number)`.

If you attempt to insert a new item with a value greater than any of the current items in the list, `start` will return NULL. So in `add`, `new->next` will be `NULL`, which is probably why it works if you add an item within the range of your list items.

You need to check if you're appending the list. If your item is going to be the final item in that list then you need to make sure that whatever the previously last item is now pointing to the new item.

Comment: I changed my while statement to the following: 

`Node** place(Node ** start, int number){
     while(*start != 0 && (*start)->value < number) {
  start = &((*start)->next);
 }
 return start; 
}`

However it seems identical to me, but now the code works, any idea why?